# could not get compatible version of lumen-framework and redis

Tags: laravel, redis, composer-php, lumen, predis

> "require": {
> "laravel/lumen-framework": "^8.0",
> "predis/predis": "^2.0",
> "illuminate/redis" : "5.1.*"
> },

lumen-framework and redis both are using illuminate/contractor, contractor version is mismatched for my lumen-framework and redis version. I could not understand what to do, I could not downgrade lumen-framework version

I could not update composer due to this package version mismatch. Unable to add new package.

Comment: Try to delete `composer.lock`, delete `vendor` folder, then `composer install` again

Comment: Yes I've deleted composer.lock file. Still it's giving error. I have copied vendor folder from another location to run this project. Deleting this vendor folder, tried also, still error.

Comment: Did you try to upgrade `illuminate/redis` version? Seems like version 5.1 is pretty old. It's should be at least ^8.0